# Using ModelBuilder to Automatically Import Excel, Display XY and Append to Master Shapefile?

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, excel, error-999999

I'm trying to automate a daily workflow using ModelBuilder. I have several tasks that I do daily in this order:

1. Import an Excel file that contains 16 fields including two fields with x and y coordinates (xcoordinate and ycoordinate). The Excel is always stored in the same folder with date as the file name.
2. Map the information using the Display XY function
3. Append the resulting shapefile to a master shapefile

I've attempted to build a model that reflects this workflow (see attached).

[image]

The model appears to run, the resulting shapefile is blank. Upon re-runs to test, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts\ExcelToTable.py", line 254, in <module>
    arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts\ExcelToTable.py", line 225, in excel_to_table
    template=tmp_table)
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 15242, in CreateTable
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The maximum record length has been exceeded.
Failed to execute (CreateTable).


Failed to execute (Excel To Table).
```

Outside the model, the excel imports into ArcMap without any issues. I've tried switching to the "1904" option in excel as well but it still does not run.

Any ideas on where the error is coming from?

I'm running ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: Try to turn off the field that you don’t want in the tables

Comment: The iterator>Excel>MakeXY>Make FeatureLayer need to feed into a collects value tool and all that needs to be in a SUB MODEL. Your current model is poorly designed as Append is executing on every loop. Search stack Exchange for this common issue.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your suggestion! I added in the collects value tool as suggested, but I'm still getting the same error...